# what does HR benefits team mean in this context?

Tags: word-usage

> An employee can direct questions to individuals, content contributors, or in a place and receive one or more responses. Often, those receiving the question are known by the questioner, and pre-qualified as a helpful resource. For example, they may turn to a team member for an answer, or contact a corporate support resource, such as the IT help desk or HR benefits team.

In the last sentence there is  "HR benefits team", I know that what HR team means. HR stand for human resource. but here benefits using "ambiguse" for me,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in a large company, the **HR department** may be more than only one person and subdivided into **several teams**.  The **benefits** team would handle things like medical benefits, pension schemes, and time-off issues.

On the other hand, your company may be giving the name **HR Benefits Team** to your HR department as an internal naming convention.  Other names that might be used are: **Human Capital Management** or **Employee Benefits**